# Azure SQL procedure add in schedulers

Tags: cron, azure-sql-database

I've got the Azure SQL procedure for migrating data from table A to table B. And I need to run this procedure at 15 min intervals.
I thought I could use Azure webjob for it, but I don't know how to call my azure sql procedure.
Are there any available schedulers in azure sql or how is it possible to make add Azure sql procedure to the Azure scheduler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option for scheduling Azure SQL Database stored procedures would be to leverage [Azure Automation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/automation/). There is a blog post which explains how to run TSQL with Azure Automation [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/26/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/). Azure Automation has a scheduler built in, however if it doesn't meet your needs, you could leverage [Azure Scheduler to schedule the Automation Runbook](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/01/27/scheduling-azure-automation-runbooks-with-azure-scheduler/) instead.